# How to hide the file path in Jw player

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, jwplayer

I  need to play the video using Jw player. It's working fine when the give the file path directly. But I need to hide or use different path to access the video file for some secure reason.

I have the following Code :-

script Code:-

```
 var playerInstance = jwplayer("track_player");
    playerInstance.setup({
      primary: "flash",
      'modes': [{ type: 'html5' }],
      file: http://localhost.com/mypro/index.php/load_video,
      provider: "http",
        type: 'mp4',
      image: "http://content.jwplatform.com/thumbs/HkauGhRi-640.jpg",
      width: 640,
      height: 360,
      title: 'A Basic Video Embed',
      description: 'A video with a basic title and description!'
    });
```

Controller Code :-

```
public function load_song(){
    $filename = base_url().'/uploads/test.mp4';
    header("Content-type: video/mp4");
    header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filename));
    readfile($filename); 
}
```

I used the above code to diplay the video using JWplayer. I got error below error message.

> Error loading media file : file not fount

Comment: Does http://localhost.com/mypro/index.php/load_video work on your browser alone? You might need to implement the Content-Range header to send parts that the video player needs. And also, doing that with PHP is very resource intensive. Let the web server do that task.

Answer (score 0):

First off the bat, it is hard to hide the file content. If it can be played by jwplayer, it can easily be seen by browser and downloaded easily by using developer tools, curl etc. You can make it harder, but cannot completely stop this.

Some comments based on your code snippet (BTW have you tried checking if you are getting any errors on the console?) :

1. file attribute is not quoted.
2. attributes modes, type are not documented. title, description are to be specified if you are using playlist interface. (Per: http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413113-configuration-options-reference)